# What is the best way to execute simple user defined scripts in Python

Tags: python, lua, scripting

I'm currently searching for some good ways how to support the execution of custom scripts in Python.

Let me present the "problem". I would like to execute some simple scripts on the data, that would accept a fixed number of arguments and return the transformed result.

Example:

```
function transform(input) {
    if(input == 1)
      return "YES"
    return "NO"
}
```

These scripts could be defined dynamically by the user. I have solved a similar problem some years ago in `.NET` by using `Lua` scripts and executing them dynamically and filling the data into the function using the `String.format`. So for example the script that user-defined looked like that:

```
function transform(input) {
  //function logic
  return transformedInput
}

return transform({0});
```

And the script was executed like this:

```
var result = Lua.run(String.format("aboveFunction", 0));
```

(I have simplified the function, since the original also had some helper functions for string operations, ... but this is not relevant to the question.)

I also looked into using Lua script in Python, but there doesn't seem to be any packages that have been maintained lately. If I have missed some package that is currently worked on, or someone has some better ideas on how to solve the described problem I will be very gratefull for all sugesstions :)

Comment: Python has `eval` function to run code passed as string.

Comment: I looked into that, and `eval` is only used for simple statements. To define functions and execute them I would need to use the `exec` function. But since Python uses indentation this would probably not be the best solution for users (hunting whitespaces). But I will keep that `eval` and `exec` in mind :)

Comment: `users hunting whitespaces` - Then you should not choose Python :-)  Try `lupa` to run Lua scripts inside Python

Comment: Yes I ended up with using lupa and running Lua scripts. This seems to be enough for my use cases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with using the `lupa` package for executing Lua scripts in my application.

So for example, I have prepared the following Lua function:

```
function(input)
  if input == 1 then
    return "{'turn': 'ON'}"
  end
  return "{'turn': 'OFF'}"
end
```

Which is the executed in the following Python code:

```
from lupa import LuaRuntime
lua = LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)

lua_func = lua.eval("""
function(input)
  if input == 1 then
    return "{'turn': 'ON'}"
  end
  return "{'turn': 'OFF'}"
end
""")
print(lua_func(1))
```

This is currently enough for my use case. I have not however tried to write some helper functions for the main function.